# MySQL: query does not return correct result

Tags: mysql

I have two tables **services** and **member_services**

[image: services]

[image]

To fetch records from **member_services** where **member_type_id = 1** I wrote

```
SELECT s.* FROM member_services ms 
LEFT JOIN services s 
ON s.ser_id = ms.ser_id 
WHERE ms.mem_id = 1 && ms.pro_id = 9 && ms.member_type_id = 1
```

but it returns

[image]

why does it returns records with **member_type_id 2** ?

what mistake I am doing in query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query's fine. The reason why it's returning **member_type_id = 2** is because you have a row in **services** called member_type_id, which doesn't correspond to the member_type_id in **member_services**.

The real issue here is a conflict of data between the two tables. If they're supposed to be the same data, it's probably best to link the two using a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.* FROM member_services ms LEFT JOIN services s 
ON ms.ser_id = s.ser_id AND ms.member_type_id = s.member_type_id
WHERE ms.mem_id = 1 AND ms.pro_id = 9 AND ms.member_type_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query instead:

```
SELECT s.* FROM member_services ms 
LEFT JOIN services s 
USING(ser_id,member_type_id) 
WHERE ms.mem_id = 1 && ms.pro_id = 9 && s.member_type_id = 1
```

I changed the ON for a **USING()** because the fields are called the same, it's kind of a shortcut.

Another difference is the use of two fields for the join (like doing `ON s.ser_id = ms.ser_id AND s.member_type_id = ms.member_type_id`). That way the filter is applied correctly.

The last change is on the `WHERE` clause, filtering the `member_type_id = 1` on the services table instead of doing it on the `member_services` table. I mean changing the ms alias to just s).

I hope it helps. Let me know if you need further assistance.